# Is the generator of a semigroup of bounded linear operators closed even when the semigroup is not strongly continuous?

Tags: operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

If $E$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is a semigroup of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ denotes the generator of $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$, is $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ closed? I know that this is true and how we prove it, when $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is strongly continuous. Is there a counterexample if $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is not strongly continuous?